# Normalising MongoDB, omitting fields from document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Having trouble getting all the fields to show up when creating a new document in MongoDB, currently the output of the below is as follows and it ignores the postTitle, postContent fields etc. Is it an issue with the schema? The docs aren't very clear.

[image]

I have a very simply Mongo DB setup like so:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

firstName: String,
lastName: String,
email: String,
hashPass: String,
userName: String,
isVerified: Boolean,
```

})

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    postDate: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
    postContent: String,
    postTitle: String,
    views: Number,
    likes: Number
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', userSchema)
```

I then try and create a post as so, injecting in the user object ID:

```
const createPost = async ( postContent, postTitle, user) => {
const post = await new PostsDb({
    user,
    postDate: Date.now(),
    postContent,
    postTitle,
    views: 0,
    likes: 0
})
await post.save()

} 


 createPost( 'bla bla', 'title of post', '5ebab7d3351253283ca610dc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post scheme, you are adding again the user shema into users.

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', userSchema)
```

For the User Model is the userSchema and for the post model is the PostSchema.

Also, my recommendation is that you make the postTitle and postContent required and avoid creating empty records.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    hashPass: String,
    userName: String,
    isVerified: Boolean,
})

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    postDate: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
    postContent: {
        type: String,
        required: true
        },
        postTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: true
        },
    views: Number,
    likes: Number
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

and

```
const post = new Post({
    user,
    postDate: Date.now(),
    postContent,
    postTitle,
    views: 0,
    likes: 0
})
await post.save()
```